# How to access element in Xamarin Forms Expander by name?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using the xamarin extended toolkit to show some Expanders in my application. What I'm trying to do is access an element in my Expander.ContentTemplate by setting x:Name. However when I try to access the element in my code-behind it doesn't find anything. What is the correct way to access any Label/Entry/Picker by name so I can manipulate it in the code-behind?

```
 <xct:Expander Margin="0,0,0,20">
                        <xct:Expander.Header>
                            <Grid>
                                <Label FontAttributes="Bold" Text="Bookings" FontSize="Medium"/>
                                <Image Source="expand.png" HorizontalOptions="End"
                                        VerticalOptions="Start">
                                    <Image.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger TargetType="Image"
                                            Binding="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type xct:Expander}}, Path=IsExpanded}"
                                            Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Source"
                                                    Value="collapse.png" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Image.Triggers>
                                </Image>
                            </Grid>
                        </xct:Expander.Header>
                        <xct:Expander.ContentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackLayout Margin="0,10">
                                    <Label x:Name="LabelDefaultPickup" FontAttributes="Bold" Text="Default Pickup location"/>
                                    <Picker x:Name="PickupPicker" ItemsSource="{Binding ActivePickupList, Source={ x:Reference profilePage}}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding naam}" SelectedIndexChanged="PickupPicker_SelectedIndexChanged"/>
                                    <Label x:Name="LabelDefaultPickupTime" FontAttributes="Bold" Text="Default Pickup time"/>
                                    <Entry x:Name="DefaultPickupTime" Placeholder="pickup time" Text="{Binding Path=uurHeen}"/>
                                    <Label x:Name="LabelDefaultDeparture" FontAttributes="Bold" Text="Default work location"/>
                                    <Entry x:Name="DefaultDeparture" Placeholder="Location id" Text="{Binding Path=corp_id}"/>
                                    <Label x:Name="LabelDefaultDepartureTime" FontAttributes="Bold" Text="Default Departure time"/>
                                    <Entry x:Name="DefaultDepartureTime" Placeholder="Location id" Text="{Binding Path=uurTerug}"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </xct:Expander.ContentTemplate>
                    </xct:Expander>
```

Comment: It will be an expect result as the `Label/Entry/Picker` is in the `DataTemplate` . We could only access the property which we binding like  `uurHeen` and `corp_id` .

Answer (score 0):

After reading the docs again, I removed the ContentTemplate tags (content is only rendered when the expander is tapped for the first time) after this change I could access an element like this:

```
 var picker = BookingExpander.FindByName("PickupPicker") as Picker;
 if (picker != null)
 {
   //do whatever you want
 }
```